# Quick action generated method position

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, position

CSharpers :)
Can I manage the location in my code of new method ? In mean *Ctrl + . * when declare a new method and VS create it below of Main, but it is located as first of all methods crated.

I`ve tried to set VS2022 setup but didnt find any setings of that.

Comment: This question is unclear, what exactly are you trying to do? Can you provide examples or snippets of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't believe you can. Just move about afterwards using the clipboard.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OK, sorry if it is unclear. When i creat new method in my code, automaticaly with tab CTRL +.  , it is situated on the top of all last method, bottom of my static void MAIN. And the question is how to set VS2022 to create it bottom of all old methods